# How can i embed mp4 video on facebook from my site

Tags: facebook, flash, video, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to share video from my site on facebook. I want the video should play on facebook rather than redirecting me on my site when i clicks on it. I have used this but it didn't work

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://website.com/files/Video.mp4" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://server.com/files/Video.mp4" /> 
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />
```

I have try to debug it using debug tool and its looks everything is perfect. Most of the example on web is explaining about sharing ".swf" files. I am wondering how can i share ".mp4" for video because its really hard for me to convert all the video into ".swf" format

Here is a sample url that i am trying to share 
http://perform-ers.com/channel/people-are-awesome/watch?m=664

Comment: Debug using: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ . You don't have a secure url specified on that page

Comment: @WizKid so is it the problem ?

Comment: That is one problem at least

Comment: I have added the secure url and now it's appearing as a video but video is not getting played. I think i have to activate ssl certificate on the website ?

Comment: @Abhijeetkumarsharma 1. Your SSL certificate has expired. 2. The url (and secure_url) should point to a video player not the video itself.

Comment: @akmozo: Thank you for your reply. I didn't get the 2nd point. can you please elaborate ? Just to let you know i am video.js. How can i point the secure_url to a video player ?

Comment: @Abhijeetkumarsharma I don't know how video.js is working exactly, but try to use the url of the video player (or a page) which playing that video like http://www.example.com/player/video.mp4 ...

Answer (score 0):

As you already found out; you need to link to a SWF file, which is the video player and which in turn (knows how to) include the video to play. You can't directly link to a MP4 file.